# C# Parallel TreeView Traversal doesn't work

Tags: c#, treeview, tree-traversal

I want to make XML file from TreeView.

Since the original traversal with foreach loop is quite slow, I'm trying to work it parallel.

I'm currently working with Visual Studio 2015.

Here is my present code for parallel TreeView traversal.

```
private Treeview _physicalTree;

public void ExportToXml_Traverse(TreeView tv, string filename)
{
    sr = new StreamWriter(filename, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    sr.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
    sr.WriteLine("<root>");

    foreach (TreeNode node in tv.Nodes)
    {
        SimpleTraverse(node);
    }

    sr.WriteLine("</root>");
    sr.Close();
}

delegate void SimpleTraverseCallBack(TreeNode root, bool parallel);
public void SimpleTraverse(TreeNode root, bool parallel = true)
{
    try
    {
        if (_physicalTree.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SimpleTraverseCallBack simpletraverser = new SimpleTraverseCallBack(SimpleTraverse);
            _physicalTree.Invoke(simpletraverser);
        }
        else
        {
            String str = "";

            for (var i = 0; i <= root.Level; i++)
                str += "  ";

            // --------------------------
            // Replace special characters
            // --------------------------

            if (root.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                String str2 = "<TR  title=\"" + root.Text + "\"  >";
                sr.WriteLine(str + str2);
                if (parallel)
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(root.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>(), node =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SimpleTraverse(node);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("[TreeToXML][Parallel] " + e.StackTrace);
                        }
                    });
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    foreach (TreeNode node in root.Nodes)
                //    {
                //        SimpleTraverse(node, false);
                //    }
                //}

                str2 = "</TR>";
                sr.WriteLine(str + str2);
            }
            else
            {
                String str2 = "<TR  title=\"" + root.Text + "\" />";
                sr.WriteLine(str + str2);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("[TreeToXML] " + e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't go to catch however, it won't finish forever.

When I examined this part of code with a breakpoint,

```
Parallel.ForEach(root.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>(), node =>
{
   //...
   SimpleTraverse(node);
   //...
});
```

> node.Bounds : System.InvalidOperationException
>
> node.IsSelected : System.InvalidOperationException

Probably this part is the problem IMHO.

Comment: The original `foreach` does not `throw` at all?

Comment: @DavidTansey Yeah. Looks like it has stucked in somewhere and never throws.